# Detecting change of getVideoTracks()[0].enabled property

Tags: webrtc

My use case is a Peer turns off their video, and I would like to display a placeholder image, not just a black screen in all connected peers.

If Peer A has setRemoteDescription for a stream from Peer B - is there any magical way Peer A will be notified of Peer B setting his PeerConnection.getVideoTracks()[0].enabled = false? <- that's how our "turn off video" is implemented

Or would this sync have to be handled by a separate messaging channel between the peers?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Received answer of discuss webRTC google group

Currently you would need a separate messaging channel to signal this.

Comment: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/discuss-webrtc/slwXpDV5cRw

The answer is literally
"Currently you would need a separate messaging channel to signal this."